# How can I concatenate two C# Lists of the type List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>. I have some duplicate values and I need those duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, concatenation

Any LINQ solutions (preferably) would be appreciated. I need the duplicate values upon concatenating both.

Comment: If you mean 'intersect' and not 'concatenate' maybe edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out which items are in both lists, you need to use the [`Enumerable.Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method.

```
    var list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
    var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

    list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1", "value1"));
    list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key2", "value2"));
    list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key1", "value1"));
    list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key3", "value3"));

    var inBothLists = list1.Intersect(list2); // contains only key1,value1
```

There are two overloads, one takes an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) so in the event that the default one does not perform the comparison the way you want, you can write and provide your own.

Comment: does the equality-comparer of `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` really check the values of `Key:T1` and `Value:T2` or an instance-based one based on the `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>`-instance (like `.ReferenceEquals()`)?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Just revised using `new KeyValuePair<string,string>("key#", "value#")` and it seems to behave as expected.

Comment: If equality-comparer of keyvalue doesn't behave as expected, go with `Tuple<string,string>` It works.